# gson deserialisition of same key different values in json

Tags: java, json

this is my json event

```
{  
  "type":"record",
  "name":"Doc",
  "doc":"adoc",
  "fields":[  
    {  
      "name":"id",
      "type":"string"
    },
    {  
      "name":"user_friends_count",
      "type":[  
        "int",
        "null"
      ]
    },
    {  
      "name":"user_location",
      "type":[  
        "string",
        "null"
      ]
    }}
```

am tring to deserialze it event but stuck with same `"type"` different values like one `"type"` with `"string"` value and other with `["string","null"]` how can i iterate them?? ths is my code

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;
import com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive;
public class FieldaDeserialisation implements JsonDeserializer<Fields>{

public Fields deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
    JsonObject jobj = json.getAsJsonObject();
    JsonArray A1 = jobj.get("fields").getAsJsonArray();
    JsonPrimitive jtype = null;
    String jname = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < jobj.size(); i++) {
        JsonElement obj = A1.get(i);
        JsonObject b1 = obj.getAsJsonObject();
        jname = b1.get("name").getAsString();
        if (b1.get("type").isJsonArray()) {
            JsonArray jarray = b1.get("type").getAsJsonArray();
            for (int j = 0; j < jarray.size(); j++) {
                jtype = (JsonPrimitive) jarray.get(j); 
            }
        }
        else {
            jtype = (JsonPrimitive) b1.get("type");
        }
    }
}
```

it shows me error on the same line `JsonArray A1 = jobj.get("fields").getAsJsonArray();` and on line1 `import java.lang.reflect.Type;` the error is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at FieldaDeserialisation.deserialize(FieldaDeserialisation.java:18)
    at FieldaDeserialisation.deserialize(FieldaDeserialisation.java:1)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:69)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter.read(ArrayTypeAdapter.java:72)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:952)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TreeTypeAdapter$GsonContextImpl.deserialize(TreeTypeAdapter.java:162)
    at JsonDataDeserialisation.deserialize(JsonDataDeserialisation.java:20)
    at JsonDataDeserialisation.deserialize(JsonDataDeserialisation.java:1)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:69)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887)
    at JsonMainClass.main(JsonMainClass.java:15)
```

this is my main deserialisation class

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;

public class JsonDataDeserialisation implements JsonDeserializer<JsonData>{

    @Override
    public JsonData deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JsonObject jobj = json.getAsJsonObject();
        String jsontype = jobj.get("type").getAsString();
        String jsonname = jobj.get("name").getAsString();
        String jsondoc = jobj.get("doc").getAsString();
        Fields[] fields = context.deserialize(jobj.get("fields"), Fields[].class);

        JsonData jdata = new JsonData();
        jdata.setType(jsontype);
        jdata.setName(jsonname);
        jdata.setDoc(jsondoc);
        jdata.setFields(fields);
        return jdata;
    }

}
```

and this is main class

```
import java.io.*;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;

public class JsonMainClass {
public static void main(String []args)throws Exception{
    String filepath = "/Users/RAGHU/Desktop/json1 .txt";
    GsonBuilder gsonb = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonb.registerTypeAdapter(JsonData.class, new JsonDataDeserialisation());
    gsonb.registerTypeAdapter(Fields.class, new FieldaDeserialisation());
    Gson gson = gsonb.create();
    try(JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(filepath))){
        reader.setLenient(true);
        JsonData jdata1 = gson.fromJson(reader, JsonData.class);
        System.out.println(jdata1);
    }
}
}
```

now this an error i got with a previous way i done

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This is not a JSON Array.
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:899)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:952)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TreeTypeAdapter$GsonContextImpl.deserialize(TreeTypeAdapter.java:162)
    at JsonDataDeserialisation.deserialize(JsonDataDeserialisation.java:20)
    at JsonDataDeserialisation.deserialize(JsonDataDeserialisation.java:1)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:69)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887)
    at JsonMainClass.main(JsonMainClass.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This is not a JSON Array.
    at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsJsonArray(JsonElement.java:106)
    at FieldaDeserialisation.deserialize(FieldaDeserialisation.java:18)
    at FieldaDeserialisation.deserialize(FieldaDeserialisation.java:1)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:69)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter.read(ArrayTypeAdapter.java:72)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: You are not getting the values with `getAsJsonArray()` this is just a method that cast the current instance(basicly). You need to get the `fields` object as an array. Then use a condition to check the type

Comment: no am passing fields object, Fields is my class and with name and type variables and Fields[] fields is my var in rootfields class

Comment: yup i edit my question with main class and deserialize class

Answer (score 0):

Calling

```
Fields[] fields = context.deserialize(jobj.get("fields"), Fields[].class);
```

You are already receiving the Array from this, just parse the json into an Array, then iterate.

```
JsonArray A1 = json.getAsJsonArray();
```

Then you can iterate like you seems to do, using the condition on the type of `type`

To be cleaner, I would use a `JsonElement` to store the field

```
JsonElement type = b1.get("type");
if(type.isJsonArray()){
    JsonArray array = type.getAsJsonArray();
    ...//ARRAY
else {
     String s = type.getAsString();
    ...//STRING
}
```

Comment: Please note that I can't test the code and don't have access to the doc, If there is some syntax error, please notify me or you are welcome to edit the code for the syntax ;-)

Comment: i changed the code to `jobj.getAsJsonArray("fields");` i got this error    `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at FieldaDeserialisation.deserialize(FieldaDeserialisation.java:18)
 at FieldaDeserialisation.deserialize(FieldaDeserialisation.java:1)
 at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:69)
 at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)`

Comment: @raghu On what line ? Could you edit your question with this stacktrace ? This would be easier ;)

Comment: @raghu, I would guess you are already passing the array to this method then ... so indeed, I was wrong saying you need to get `fields`, you could do `json.getAsJsonArray()`

Comment: @raghu edited, you are already receiving the array here (this was not mention, sorry(

Comment: now i got the error has shown in above question dont know where iam going wrong is that in my loop where i get the type array value??

Comment: Print the JSON object or use the debugger to be sure you are receiving the JSON you think.